# Why is some mass converted to energy during some alpha decay processes?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

I am not a physics expert. I wanted to know why it is that during some alpha decay processes some mass is converted to energy. Where does this mass come from? An example that I had in my book was the decay of radium-226 to radon-222.

Answer (score 2):

The mass of radium-226 is greater than the mass of radon-222 plus the mass of an alpha particle.

The difference in the total mass before and after the decay $\Delta m$ ends up as the kinetic energy $E$ of the daughter nucleus and the alpha article with $E=\Delta mc^2$.

The reason for the decay is that the radium-226 nucleus is unstable and is trying to move to a more stable state by decaying into radon-222.

Radon-222 is also unstable and in turn decays as shown below.

[image]

You will see that this continues until a stable isotope of lead Pb-206 reached.
The times which are shown are the half lives of the nuclei.
During each decay some mass is converted into energy and the nucleus s moving towards a stable state.

**Update**

The mass difference for this decay $\Delta m  = 226.025403 \rm u - (222.017571 u + 4.002603 u ) = 
+0.005229 u $ where I have put in the masses of the parent and daughter nuclei and the alpha particle in atomic mass units (u) where 12 u is the mass of a carbon-12 atom.

Comment: but what is the nature of the mass defect? The mass of the alpha particle plus the mass of the radon-222 will not give you the mass of the radium-226. What is the nature of the mass that gets converted to energy? [Note: thank you very much for answering.]

Comment: You will find that nuclei have masses smaller than the sum of the masses of free protons plus free neutrons assembled to make them. This is the binding energy of the nucleus. It comes from intra-nuclear forces (I.e. strong and weak). Just like the binding energy of the Sun plus Earth system. For some nuclei, there is more binding energy to be gained by spitting out an alpha particle to make two nuclei. So it does so.

Comment: I think it's better to call your mass difference calculation the Q of the reaction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_value_(nuclear_science)).  Mass defect is associated with the difference in actual mass versus A (http://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/howtosolveit/Nuclear/nuclear_binding_energy.htm  and others)

Comment: @BillN Thank you for you comment. I did not want to call the mass difference the Q-value of the reaction because I think that the Q-value of a reaction is the energy released rather than the difference in mass.  So what I have done is changed to using difference in mass and not used the term mass defect.

Answer (score 0):

Mass and energy are intimately related via the famous $E = mc^2$. In a compound system, not only do the masses of its constituents contribute to total energy, but the potential energy of the system can also contribute to its mass.

For example, a compressed spring is more massive than an uncompressed one - but the contribution is negligible due to the smallness of the conversion factor $c^{-2} \approx 1.1\times 10^{-17} \mathrm{kg}/\mathrm{J}$. At nuclear scales, the effect is just more pronounced.